# VBA FilesystemObject

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a problem with this function in VBA that saves certain columns to text file.
It only saves the values of Column B, and it ignores the another for loop wherein I loop in the values of the Column C. I tried to add a direct writing to file ->  objTextStream.writeline ("COPY THIS STRING") just to see where's the problem but still COPY THIS STRING still wasn't saved in the text file.

What's seems to be the problem. Thanks in advance guys.

```
Sub SaveToTxt(toRange As Integer)

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyRange2 As Range
Dim objFileSyatem As Object, objTextStream As Object
Dim cell As Range


Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range _
("B1:B" + CStr(toRange) & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

Set MyRange2 = ActiveSheet.Range _
("C1:C" + CStr(toRange) & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)


'create filesystem and textstream objects, the name of the .txt file
'is one of parameters of CreateTextFile method
Set objFileSyatem = CreateObject( _
"Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextStream = objFileSyatem.CreateTextFile( _
"C:\Users\wmeniola\work work work\Ranges deletion\test.txt", True)

'loop through all cells in MyRange and save contents as
'separate lines in newly created .txt file
For Each cell In MyRange.Cells
objTextStream.writeline (cell.Value)
Next

For Each cell In MyRange2.Cells
objTextStream.writeline (cell.Value)
Next


objTextStream.writeline ("COPY THIS STRING")
objTextStream.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all I think you should write `objTextStream.writeline "COPY THIS STRING"` without ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the line

```
Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range _
  ("B1:B" + CStr(toRange) & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
```

It is creating a larger range than you expect.

For example, if there are say 100 rows of data in columns `A` and you call your sub with `toRange` = 100, you will get `MyRange` = `B1:B100100`.  This will print a whole lot of blank rows to your text file!

I think you want just

```
Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & toRange)
```

and similarly for `MyRange2`

Or, don't bother passing `toRange`, and use

```
With ActiveSheet
    Set MyRange = .Range("B1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Can I have a follow up inquiry regarding this as I was just starting to use VBA. Can I have a choice of saving it to .SQL format instead instead of textfile? What would be the function as the current function im using is CreateTextFile()

Comment: Sure, a clarification is fine.

Comment: Can I have a choice of saving it to .SQL format instead instead of textfile? What would be the function as the current function im using is CreateTextFile()

Comment: If by "SQL format" you mean insert into a database, use a different object (eg ado). If you mean creating a SQL command file as text, fso is fine, just specify a different file extension when you create the file.

Comment: Oh got it. I am specifying a different file extension of SQL but it doesn't work yet I found out that I have a missing "\" in the path. Thanks btw for the help. Appreciate it a lot.